# Grails : Call JS from Controller

Tags: grails

I have a controller with a method in it:

```
class teachController {

   def updateIndex () {

    // Do something here
    ----------
  }
}
```

Now in the GSP there's a JavaScript function:

```
var drawIndex (var indexValues) {

  // Do something here
 -----------------
  }
```

How can i call the above JavaScript function from inside the controller function?

Comment: There're a way, like using Rhino or Hashorn. But I believe it's not what you want. What are you trying to do, why do you need this?

Comment: I want to update a table with data dynamically from the controller.

Comment: what do you mean? data in a browser from data on server? at this case it's  opposite, js should call server controller to get data, isn't it?

Comment: Well, that gives me another idea! :-)
Still i would like to know whether it's possible to call JS function in GSP from a Controller groovy file.

Comment: that's possible by using a server-side javascript interpreter, as I said before, like Rhino/Hashorn. But I don't think anybody really do that, it doesn't make any sense, at least for GSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is to update a table with data dynamically from the controller.
I would use ajax to execute the javascript function "drawIndex()" after it calls the controller action "updateIndex()".

```
class teachController {
    def updateIndex(){
         // Do something here
          withFormat {
                json {  
                    render indexValues as JSON
                }
          }
    }
}
```

Then from your gsp you call the controller action by the name updateIndex.json and using remoteFunction

```
function dynamicallyUpdateTable(){
    ${remoteFunction(
           action: 'updateIndex.json',
           onSuccess: 'drawIndex(data)' 
                    )
   }
}
```

This will call your javascript function

```
 function drawIndex(indexValues){
        // Do something here
        //console.log(indexValues)
    }
```

And that should work. (at least in the way I like to do it) Hope it helps.